# Kotlin Unable to login in Agora while real time messaging

Tags: kotlin, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Trying to login using temp token from dashboard but unable to login

// Log in to the RTM system

```
mRtmClient!!.login(token_, uid, object : ResultCallback<Void?> {
            override fun onSuccess(responseInfo: Void?) {
                logValue("login Success ")
                joinChannel()
            }

            override fun onFailure(errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {  logValue("login failed "+ errorInfo.errorDescription) }
        })
```

getting  login failed LOGIN_ERR_INVALID_TOKEN

Comment: token generated from server is also getting same error

Comment: Make sure that the primary certificate is enabled in your project.

Comment: yes primary certificate is enabled and I had tried using temp token generated in console also, but getting same error, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using both RTC and RTM?

Comment: My goal is to use both for testing purpose I am trying with RTM alone

Comment: In case you're using both then please switch to the Agora token server. You can find the code for that over here: http://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service